# Python Threading - Out of Memory

Tags: python, optimization, python-multithreading

I currently am working on a problem in python to determine the most optimal route to take when scheduling deliveries. The high-level understanding of my code is that I read in all the buildings (values before the ':' in the input), then calculate all possibilities for routes to these buildings. Then I split computation up into a thread for each combination that is generated and return the total amount of time to return back to the 'home' building (building 'abc' in all cases).

My code below works fine on a smaller subset of data (total of 4 buildings), but when I blow my code up to 13 buildings (the required amount). I'm running into a `Memory Error` during execution.

I'm a bit stuck on how I can go about resolving this issue, I've never encountered a problem that blows up this exponentially before. My solution must include threading. Any suggestions/tips would be extremely appreciated.

Input.txt (Small Subset):

```
abc : 0 5 7 3
def : 4 0 3 6
ghi : 6 4 0 4
jkl : 4 5 6 0
```

Input.txt (Full data):

```
abc : 0 5 7 3 2 4 6 2 1 5 8 4 5
def : 4 0 3 6 7 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 6
ghi : 6 4 0 4 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 7
jkl : 4 5 6 0 2 3 7 8 6 9 2 8 3
mno : 1 2 3 4 0 9 8 7 6 5 3 2 2
pqr : 9 8 3 4 1 0 9 8 3 5 7 9 2
stu : 1 8 9 4 2 1 0 9 8 7 2 1 1
vwx : 3 2 1 9 4 1 5 0 9 8 2 5 8
yza : 1 9 8 2 3 7 4 6 0 1 4 2 6
bcd : 8 9 1 4 6 2 4 2 1 0 9 3 4
efg : 7 7 7 7 8 9 1 2 3 9 0 4 3
hij : 6 1 2 4 9 0 2 1 3 9 1 0 8
klm : 1 6 3 8 3 5 9 4 7 2 1 5 0
```

Current Code:

```
import time
import os
import threading
import sys
from itertools import permutations
from functools import reduce


inputFile = 'Input.txt'
outputFile = 'output2.txt'

f=open(inputFile,'r')
line=f.readline()
buildings=[]
timings=[]
results={}

def run_me(TimeMatrix,combination,results,buildingDict):
    my_lock.acquire()
    results[' '.join(map(str, combination))] = GenerateTiming(TimeMatrix,combination,buildingDict)
    my_lock.release()

def GenerateTiming(TimeMatrix,combination,buildingDict):
    current=combination
    mySum=[]
    for i in range(len(current)-1):
        currentBuilding=buildingDict[current[i]]
        nextBuilding=buildingDict[current[i+1]]
        mySum.append(TimeMatrix[currentBuilding-1][nextBuilding])
    result=sum(mySum)
    return(result)


while line: 
    b=line.split(":")[0]
    t=line.split(":")[1]
    b=b.strip()
    t=t.strip()
    buildings.append(b)
    timings.append(t)
    home=buildings[0]
    line=f.readline()



combinations=[]
first, *rest = buildings
for p in permutations(rest):
    combinations.append([first,*p,first])

bldLKP=combinations[0]
buildingDict={}

for i in range(1,len(bldLKP)):
    buildingDict[bldLKP[i-1]] = i
    i=i+1


TimeMatrix=[[i] + [int(n) for n in s.split()] for i, s in enumerate(timings, 1)]

#Threading Section
my_lock=threading.Lock()
my_threads=list()


for comb in combinations:
    my_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=run_me,args=(TimeMatrix,comb,results,buildingDict)))

for current_thread in my_threads:
    current_thread.start()

for current_thread in my_threads:
    current_thread.join()


lowest=min(results.values())
final=[key for key in results if results[key]==lowest]

print(' '.join(map(str, final)),lowest)
```

EDIT: I should mention I believe the issue is in the following code where I am identifying all possible combinations of buildings. However, I'm not sure how I can do it any other way because every path needs to be checked for the fastest route.

```
combinations=[]
first, *rest = buildings
for p in permutations(rest):
    combinations.append([first,*p,first])
```

Comment: You should look this site: "The most direct solution would be to try all permutations (ordered combinations) and see which one is cheapest (using brute-force search). The running time for this approach lies within a polynomial factor of O(n!), the factorial of the number of cities, so this solution becomes impractical even for only 20 cities."<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem>

Comment: Why use threading instead of multiprocessing?

Comment: @AMC I edited my original question. My solution needs to use threading.

Comment: Oh, that's an odd restriction, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you create permutations and than run thread to calculate sum(time) for each route. amount thread your code run is

Small subset (4 buildings)

you create permutations for rest of the buildings(not including first one) so the amount will be (4-1)! = 3 * 2 * 1 = 6

Full data (13 buildings)
(13-1)! = 479001600 (such amount of threads should be created.

I would suggest not to use threads for this case.

I wrote simple recursive function that implement what you need. I has a big performance improvement against permutations. It does not go deeper if current time is greater than min time. Please take a look of my implementation

```
import threading

time_matrix = {}
buildings = []

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = []
    for row in f.readlines():
        building, line = row.split(':')
        building = building.strip()
        buildings.append(building)
        lines.append(line.strip())
        time_matrix[building] = {}

for building, line in zip(buildings, lines):
    for index, time_to_reach in enumerate(line.split(' ')):
        to_building = buildings[index]
        time_matrix[building][to_building] = int(time_to_reach)

first, *rest = buildings


results = []
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, time_matrix, current_building, to_visit_buildings, current_path, current_time):
        super().__init__()
        self.time_matrix = time_matrix
        self.current_building = current_building
        self.to_visit_buildings = to_visit_buildings
        self.current_path = current_path
        self.current_time = current_time

    def run(self):
        min_time, min_paths = self.calculate(self.time_matrix, self.current_building, self.to_visit_buildings, self.current_path, self.current_time)
        if min_paths and min_time:
            results.append((min_time, min_paths))

    def calculate(self, time_matrix, current_building, to_visit_buildings, current_path, current_time, min_time=None, min_paths=None):

        if min_paths and min_time < current_time:
            return None, None

        if not to_visit_buildings:
            current_time += time_matrix[current_building][first]
            if min_time is None or min_time > current_time:
                path = [first, *current_path, first]
                if min_time == current_time:
                    return current_time, min_paths + [path]
                else:
                    return current_time, [path]

        for building in to_visit_buildings:
            new_to_visit_buildings = [b for b in to_visit_buildings if b != building]
            new_current_path = [*current_path, building]
            new_current_time = current_time + time_matrix[current_building][building]
            new_min_time, new_min_paths = self.calculate(time_matrix, building, new_to_visit_buildings, new_current_path, new_current_time, min_time, min_paths)
            if new_min_paths and new_min_time and (not min_time or new_min_time < min_time):
                min_time = new_min_time
                min_paths = new_min_paths

        return min_time, min_paths

my_threads = []
for building in rest:
    to_visit = [b for b in rest if b != building]
    current_time = time_matrix[first][building]
    my_threads.append(MyThread(time_matrix, building, to_visit, [building], current_time))

for current_thread in my_threads:
    current_thread.start()

for current_thread in my_threads:
    current_thread.join()

min_paths, min_time = min(results, key=lambda r: r[0])

print(min_paths, min_time)
```

for full data it outputs:
['abc', 'yza', 'bcd', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'efg', 'stu', 'hij', 'vwx', 'def', 'pqr', 'mno', 'klm', 'abc'] 20

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm required to use threads as part of a solution.

Comment: In this case you need to create for example 20 threads and spread load.

Comment: please check code again I updated it to use multithreading. But it does not give boost in performance

Comment: If I needed to account for paths that tied, and print all paths with the same distance, how should I modify the above code? I tried working through the calculate function but every time I only got 1 answer.